# Need help to format a table

Tags: tables

I'm not a LaTaX user at all but like to create some tables because they are outstanding.

I put togehter some code (below) but are not totally happy with the outcome and could no manage to get what I want, hope someone can help me, what I would like to change is the follwing:

1. Have "Kruskall-Wallis Group" centered
2. Have the x2 column slightly more to the left
3. Have "group" and and "p" centered under the post-hoc stats

Appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[
  convert={
    density=300 -alpha deactivate,
    size=1080x1080,
    outext=.png
  },
]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document} 

{}

\begin{tabular}{cc@{}cclllllll@{}}\toprule
&  \multicolumn{0}{c}{Kruskal-Wallis  Group}  &  &  &   \multicolumn{3}{c} {Conover-Iman post-hoc}                        \\
\cmidrule (lll){2-4}  \cmidrule(rl){5-6}
 Month & Treat & x2 &  piiii  & group & p \\  
 
 \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule (lll){2-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-6}


  & synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control & 0.007 & \\
   June 2022 & commercial& 7.34           & 0.05 & commercial vs control &  0.0001 \\

   & control& 1.00&  0.1 &  commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\

 
\bottomrule


\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: (1) Your tablular has too many column specifications. (2) It's unnecessary to say `\cmidrule(lll)`. If you need to trim the left side, only one `l` is enough. (3) Your example need the `booktabs` package but you don't show it in your code.

Comment: I copied the document class from somewhere. I have these package: \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

Comment: A complete code example should begin with `\documentclass{...}`.

Comment: \documentclass[
  convert={
    density=300 -alpha deactivate,
    size=1080x1080,
    outext=.png
  },
]{standalone}

Comment: SO why not modify the code?@Tazmania

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attempt is good, but there are several errors:

- `\multicolumn{0}` doesn't really make sense;
- `\cmidrule(lll)` specifies three times the same thing;
- you define eleven columns and only use six.

These are coding errors. Next there are typographical ones:

- “Month” is a header at the same level as Kruskal-Wallis Group and Conover-Iman post-hoc;
- June 2022 should be at the top of the group; missing values below it are understood to be the same;
- the subheaders should be probably all centered in the respective column, even if the column is left aligned.

In order to separate groups of data, you can use some vertical space or a `\midrule`, but I recommend the latter only to separate conceptually different parts of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}llcclc@{}}
\toprule
Month &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kruskal-Wallis  Group} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Conover-Iman post-hoc} \\
\cmidrule (lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Treat} & x2 &  piiii  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{group} & p \\  
\midrule
June 2022
& synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    &  0.007 \\
& commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     &  0.0001 \\
& control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\
\addlinespace
July 2022
& synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    &  0.007 \\
& commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     &  0.0001 \\
& control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\
\addlinespace
August 2022
& synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    &  0.007 \\
& commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     &  0.0001 \\
& control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here I use `article` to avoid complications and post processing.

[image]

A possible improvement is to align the figures at the decimal separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  l
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Month &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kruskal-Wallis  Group} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Conover-Iman post-hoc} \\
\cmidrule (lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Treat} & {x2} &  {piiii}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{group} & {p} \\  
\midrule
June 2022
& synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    &  0.007 \\
& commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     &  0.0001 \\
& control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\
\addlinespace
July 2022
& synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    &  0.007 \\
& commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     &  0.0001 \\
& control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\
\addlinespace
August 2022
& synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    &  0.007 \\
& commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     &  0.0001 \\
& control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized &  0.415 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for everyones input that solved my problems with the table.

Answer (score 4):

My main recommendation would be that you align the numbers in columns 3, 4, and 6 on their respective decimal markers. This may be achieved by loading the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and employing that package's `S` column type for the three columns in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  convert={
    density=300 -alpha deactivate,
    size=1080x1080,
    outext=.png
  },
  border=2pt
]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
                    l 
                    S[table-format=2.2]
                    S[table-format=1.3]
                    l
                    S[table-format=1.4] @{}}
\toprule
Month
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kruskal-Wallis Group}  
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Conover-Iman post-hoc} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
& Treat & {x2} & {piiii}  & group & {p} \\  
\midrule
  & synthesized & 10.6 & 0.001 & synthesized vs control    & 0.007  \\
June 2022 
  & commercial  & 7.34 & 0.05  & commercial vs control     & 0.0001 \\
  & control     & 1.00 & 0.1   & commercial vs synthesized & 0.415  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```